# how to show null date fields as a empty space in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

while retrieving and showing empty date field it showing as 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM .
aspx code

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Completed dt">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("TaskCompletedDt")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>

                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskCompletedDt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TaskCompletedDt") %>'>
                  </asp:TextBox>

                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
![enter image description here][1]
```

i managed to insert null values in db

```
TaskCompletedDt = 
    CASE WHEN TaskCompletedDt = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN '' 
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TaskCompletedDt, 103) 
    END
```

Comment: Just use  string.IsNullOrEmpty() method with ternary(?) operator

Comment: where to use , can u elaborate plz @SainPradeep

Comment: try this <%# DateTime.Compare(Eval("TaskCompletedDt"), new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)) == 0 ? "": Eval("TaskCompletedDt") %>

Answer (score 2):

If you think this is inserting `NULL` values in your database, then you're mistaken:

```
TaskCompletedDt = 
    CASE WHEN TaskCompletedDt = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN '' 
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TaskCompletedDt, 103) 
    END
```

You are passing an empty string to SQL Server, which is in turn defaulting to the default `DATETIME` value of `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

If you actually want to store a `NULL` or retrieve a NULL value, pass in `NULL`.

```
TaskCompletedDt = 
    CASE WHEN TaskCompletedDt = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN NULL 
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TaskCompletedDt, 103) 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using eval and comparing to the default null time?

```
 text='<%#IIF(Eval("TaskCompletedDt") = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', "", DateField) %>'
```

Something like this should do what you want, the first section is just the value you want to evaluate, if the first statement is true, you want to set it to " ", and if Eval("TaskCompletedDt") does not equal that date you want the value to be your real date.

Answer (score 0):

Write the query inside the codebehind for display of grid. It actually works..

````
string query = "SELECT distinct val1,val2,(case when year(convert(date,DATE,103)) <= 1900 then null else DATE end) as Date FROM tablename";```
````